# How can I assign an existing simple product to a configurable product using the admin interface?

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-2.1, configurable-product

I have existing simple products I need to assign to configurable products, however I can't find any interface to do this. This was possible in Magento 1, but I can't see where it is possible in Magento 2.

The only configurations interface I can see will only allow the creation of new products:

[image: Screenshot of configurable product admin interface]

Is there a way to associate existing simple products to existing configurable products using the admin interface?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Magento 2 you need to first use the **Create configurations** tool to create the simple products to associate, then you need to replace the auto-generated versions with the simple products you actually want.

[image: Magento2 configurable product options]

Comment: Thank you for this. For those interested, a closed [GitHub issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2564) on the problem, where it is stated:

"Additionally, we have internal ticket MAGETWO-50639 in our backlog to revise the flow for configurable product."

Comment: When we click on it, it will not allow us to assign simple products to the Configurable products.

Comment: you can see this extensions for [Simple Configurable Products](https://www.mageants.com/simple-configurable-products-extension-for-magento-2.html)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is an option to **choose/add/associate** existing simple products to existing configurable products In Admin interface.

**Follow the below steps:**

1. Open the **Product -> Catalog** from admin interface.
2. Open the **configurable product** where you actually want to assign/associate simple product.
3. Now, From there configurable product form you will see **Configurations** option.
4. Click on that option you will see an option "**Add Products Manually**"
5. Click on that **It will open your simple products grid** on the popup. Select the simple products which you want to assign.
6. Click on **Done** on the top right corner, Save your configurable product. You have successfully assign simple product to the configurable product.
7. For more details refer below screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Actually, the `Add Products Manually` link does not show until first going through the `Create Configurations` process.

Comment: @DannyNimmo Yes thats correct !!!  Because when you create configurable product !! then you need to select/give its configuration(kind of attributes) Based on that it will allow to select products . But your Question is for existing configurable product and for existing simple products... Hope you got it

Comment: But it does not make sense. You first need to make some placeholder configurations for a random attribute so that you're allowed to Add Products Manually, that's a lot of steps. A workaround could be to comment out line 312-315 in `vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\ConfigurablePanel.php` so the `Add Products Manually` button always shows, but it won't work because then you haven't selected the attribute on which to create the configurations from.

Comment: However, I understand Magento's decision to make it like this. It makes more sense to generate the underlying Simple products when creating the Configurable Products. Instead of (the old way) creating some Simple Products and then creating a Configurable product and assigning those Simple products to it. This new approach is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Go to **Product --> Catalog** from Admin panel.

Then Click on **Configurable Product** from **Add Product** button.

Now scroll down you will see the **Configuration section** and unfold it.

By default, it will not show **Add Product Manually** option. So, first click on **create configuration** and follow all the steps.

It will now show you new product combinations with the attributes options you have selected. Then remove this product.

Now you will see the **Add Product Manually** option and now you can add all simple products easily. Once it's done click on **Save Config.**

Answer (score -2):

Hope this saves someone the time I've wasted trying to find an answer and a whole lot of trial and error.

1. In Magento 1, you assigned **simple** products to the configurable
   product.
2. In Magento 2, you assign **virtual** products to the
   configurable product you have created.

**If a user creates a Simple product and then want to use it with a Configurable product, they can't. They have to recreate this product as a Virtual product.**

If anyone knows of a better way, please let me know.

Comment: Actually a virtual product is created automatically if you do not put a weight. That's why Magento 2 consider that it's a virtual product.